# Remove elements from recursive array from bottom to top in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

Given the following array:

```
array(
    0 => array(
        0 => 56,
        1 => array(
            0 => 57,
            1 => 58,
            2 => 59,
        ),
        2 => 60
    ),
    1 => array(
        0 => 61,
        1 => array(
            0 => 62,
            1 => array(
                0 => 63,
                1 => 64
            )
        )
    )
)
```

How could I proceed to remove elements from that array starting from deepest elements? My elements are ID in a database and key constraints make me unable to delete parents if they have children...

I looked for something using [RecursiveIterator](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.recursivearrayiterator.php) but no solution so far...

---

### EDIT

Actually, no need to get a specific algo, a standard recursion will do the job

Comment: You need to traverse the array from the deepest element to the parent element to delete the records from Database. right?

Comment: Yes, but I can achieve this from parents to children: if my parent has children, go through the children and delete. Then recheck if it still has children. If no, delete it and go on

Comment: Can you explain little bit more. you need the Ids in the form of 56, 57, 58 ...?

Comment: I need to remove first 57, 58, 59, then, 56, then 60, then 63, 64, then 62, then 61

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can visit leaves only with [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) and `RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY` mode and then reverse the resulting array:

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator($ids),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
);

$ids = [];

foreach ($iterator as $id) {
    // You can put elements directly in the beggining of an array
    // or reverse array later.
    // array_unshift($ids, $id);
    $ids[] = $id;
}

$ids = array_reverse($ids);
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0336f42ae59eb7cd5e64e1b380940d05a5ffe775).

Comment: That's it! Great! Thank you!